# Compare a character

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is passing a char to a method and it compares.

The method is as follows.

```
public static readonly int N = 1;
int facing = N;

public int charIntoInt(char face)
{
    if (face == 'N')
    {
        facing = 1;
    }
    else if (face == 'E')
    {
        facing = 2;
    }
    else if (face == 'S')
    {
        facing = 3;
    }
    else if (face == 'W')
    {
        facing = 4;
    }
    return facing;
}
```

But everytime I pass any charactor like E,S,W it only return 1. How to solve this issue?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Is `facing` a class variable or something?

Comment: define `facing` in `charIntoInt` method

Comment: A switch will be cleaner than a big if case.`switch(face){case 'N':return 1;break;case 'E':return 2;break; [...] }`

Comment: post the code where you call charIntoInt method end use switch :)

Comment: What is "N" that is being passed to the variable?

Comment: How about putting a runnable example on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com)?

Comment: Instead of letting us guess what the problem is, please post a complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Okay, so default value of facing is 1. Now show us how you called that function

Comment: Make `facing` an internal variable in the method, it already returns a value, having method to modify a member variable implicitly while it returns a value is a bad design.

Comment: how you assign `facing = n` do you mean `facing = charIntoInt(N)`?

Comment: If you have only one return value per case, you don't have to manipulate the variable 'facing', you can return the value directly.

Comment: http://ideone.com/jutiwi here is the complete code

Comment: Little thing, if you never assign values to your readonly variables, use const variables instead of readonly.

Comment: what is the value of `face` at runtime? Are you certain it will always be N, E, W or S? Because if it isn't, the default value 1 will be returned.

Comment: What characters do you type  in console ? You have a line in your code `String startingPoint = Console.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. 
But as you have initiated N=1 for any non matching value, it will return '1'. 
Even if you change the case like 'e'. 
So int i = charIntoInt('s'); -- will always return '1'. But int i = charIntoInt('S'); -- will return 2.

Comment: Use `ToUpperInvariant()` to get off this problem. `char facing = startingPoint[2].ToUpperInvariant()` ;

Answer (score 0):

Another variant using an enum to hold the directions:

```
enum Facing {
    Unknown = 0,
    N = 1,
    E = 2,
    S = 3,
    W = 4
}
```

Convert char to enum:

```
var character = 'N';
Facing facing = (Facing)Enum.Parse(typeof(Facing), character.ToString());
```

Convert enum to int:

```
int numericFacing = (int) facing;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var facing = 0;
```

instantiate facing, it is only present in the block scope{} you are using it in currently.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: The thing is, facing must already be instated, or else he could not even run it. So the question is how does he call the function? You assume he can't even compile the code while he clearly states that he called the function, implying that he could compile his code...

Comment: In his case, he doesn't needs this variable. He can return the value directly.